# What does it mean when my win streak is 0?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

My win streak is "zero." That is... odd. I mean, when I had a win streak of −3 that probably meant I lost thrice in a row, but zero? What does *that* mean?

[image: Win streak zero]

Answer (score 6):

When you win after a loss, your win streak is set to one.

When you lose after a win, your win streak is set to zero.

If your win streak is −3, that means you lost *four* times in a row, not three.